# Category of object-orientation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

Object-oriented languages can be categorized into two:

- Class-based: like C++
- Prototype-based: like JavaScript.

Ruby has class, so it is class-based. But its class is also an object. So is Ruby still a class-based language, or is it  something in between? Is this a third category?

EDIT:

Ok, what I was wondering is, is other class-based language doing same thing like ruby, like create a class object of class Class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an object-oriented language, what else would a class be, than an object? If one of the most important things in an object-oriented language weren't an object, then the language wouldn't be very object-oriented, would it?

Classes are objects in many class-based OO languages. Smalltalk, Python, Ruby, Newspeak, you name it. There are some languages where they aren't, e.g. Java and C#, but even there you can get a reflective proxy object which represents a class.

Comment: yeah, you got to have some kind of representation of class. thanks.
i've read some book about different OO language, 
only ruby book talk about the representation. so i was kinda thinking
class in other OO language is some abstract concept and didn't relate it with object:)

Answer (score 0):

`Class` is an instance of `Class` class. There is nothing in Ruby that goes against it being class based.